Greens Function Partial Derivative Symmetry
I am trying to understand if, in general, there is some sort of symmetry in partial derivatives of a greens function w.r.t. the first and second (unprimed and primed) variable.
For a self-adjoint linear differential operator $L$,
$Lg(x,x') = \delta(x,x'),$
$L=L^\dagger, g = g^\dagger$
we have in general (Hilbert inner-product)
$g(x,x') = g(x',x)^*$.
If the coefficients of the underlying DE are real, than
$g(x,x') = g(x',x)$,
so $g(x,x')$ itself is symmetric.
Now I am wondering if we can say something similar when it comes to derivatives. Here it is shown that
$\frac{\partial g(x,x')}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g(x',x)}{\partial x'}$,
but no statement is made about the relationship between $\frac{\partial g(x,x')}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial g(x,x')}{\partial x'}$. However, looking at the specific greens function that solves the wave equation with point-source excitation
$(\nabla^2+k^2)g(r,r') = -\delta(r,r')$,
$g(r,r')=\frac{e^{jkR}}{4\pi R}$,
$R=\sqrt{(x_1-x_1')^2+(x_2-x_2')^2+(x_3-x_3')^2}$,
it is true that
$\frac{\partial g(x_1,x_2,x_3;x_1',x_2',x_3')}{\partial x_j} = - \frac{\partial g(x_1,x_2,x_3;x_1',x_2',x_3')}{\partial x'_j}$,
e.g.,
$\nabla g(x_1,x_2,x_3;x_1',x_2',x_3') = -\nabla' g(x_1,x_2,x_3;x_1',x_2',x_3')$.
Is this true for any greens function in case we have an self-adjoint operator with real coefficients?


Is this true for any greens function in case we have an self-adjoint operator with real coefficients?

No.  For example, consider the Green's function for the Laplacian $\nabla^2 u = 0$ on $[0,1]$, subject to the Dirichlet boundary conditions $u(0) = u(1) = 0$.  We have
$$
G(x,x') = \begin{cases} x'(1 - x) & x > x' \\ x(1 - x') & x \leq x' \end{cases}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{\partial G(x, x')}{\partial x} = \begin{cases} -x' & x > x' \\ 1 - x' & x \leq x' \end{cases}
$$
but
$$
\frac{\partial G (x, x')}{\partial x'} = \begin{cases} 1-x & x > x' \\ x & x \leq x' \end{cases}.
$$
On an intuitive level, the property $\partial G/\partial x = - \partial G/\partial x'$ in your example is a consequence of the property $G(x,x') = f(x - x')$, i.e., the Green's function only depends on the separation of $x$ and $x'$.  If a PDE problem has translational symmetry, then there will (usually) exist a Green's function with this property.  But in the case I've outlined above, the boundary conditions break the translational symmetry, and so the conjecture fails.

Thank you, Michael. Maybe the statement mentioned is true only if the boundary is at infinity, as is is the case for a "free-space" greens function, like the one I have given as an example.

@3ak:  Not necessarily.  Periodic boundary conditions on a compact domain (like $u(0) = u(1)$, $u'(0) = u'(1)$ on $[0,1]$) could also yield the "translational symmetry" needed for your property to hold.
